# In Xcode 5, is there a shortcut to move up one option in the autocomplete list?

Tags: xcode5

For example, I'm currently on viewDidUnload. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will let me go to the next option(viewWillAppear). Is there a shortcut to make the cursor go up one option(viewDidLoad)?

[image]
.

I know this is tedious, but it's been very annoying to me because I don't want to move my hand to the up and down key every time I type a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: @IanRoberts You are right! Thanks! I'll accept it if you wnat to make it a answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about XCode in particular but in similar situations in other apps I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> is the usual counterpart to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> ("previous" vs. "next" perhaps?).  These are the standard bindings in the [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-Point.html) editor, along with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> for left and right ("backward" and "forward" respectively).